# Purple Screen After Clean Install

Tags: boot

I've been trying to install Ubuntu for awhile now, and have been pretty much 100% unsuccessful, aside from the LiveCD portion of it.

So my issue is this: I successfully reach the GRUB menu, but choosing anything related to Ubuntu at that point simply causes a purple screen.

I tried to launch it in Recovery mode, and it ended up with the same screen.

I edited the startup commands for the main boot option and replaced "quiet splash" with nomodeset, changed the $linuxgfxmode to nomodeset, and pretty much tried everything, but I cannot in any way get Ubuntu to boot.

I have an AMD A8-4500M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics x 4.

The Boot-Repair program said something about the EFI settings, and that I was in Legacy mode. What does this mean? Is it a problem with the installation?

I have no real idea of what to do. Any and all help would be appreciated.